# Memory management in iOS / ManagedObjectContext

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, autorelease, convenience-methods

Looks like I did not understand memory management in Objective C... sigh.

I have the following code (note that in my case, `placemark.thoroughfare` and `placemark.subThoroughfare` are both filled with valid data, thus both `if`-conditions will be `TRUE`

`item` is tied to a `ManagedObjectContext`. The managed variables in `item` such as `place` have setters/getters created with `@dynamic`. Thus, the declaration is

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *place;
@dynamic place;
```

Later in the code, in the ReverseGeocoderDelegate, I access it:

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {

if (placemark.thoroughfare) {
    [item.place release];
    item.place = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", placemark.thoroughfare];        
} else {
    [item.place release];
    item.place = @"Unknown Place";
}
if (placemark.thoroughfare && placemark.subThoroughfare) {
// *** problem is here ***
    [item.place release];
    item.place = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", placemark.thoroughfare , placemark.subThoroughfare];
}
```

If I do not release `item.place` at the marked location in the code, Instruments finds a memory leak there. If I do, the program crashes as soon as I try to access `item.place` outside the offending method.

Any ideas?

Comment: It’d be useful to paste the declaration of the `place` property, as well as the definition of its setter method (if any).

Comment: Do you mean you generated your getters/setters with `@synthesize`?

Comment: I used @dynamic, as I understood this is the right thing for properties tied to a ManagedObjectContext as in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would change the logic like this:

```
NSString *newPlace = nil;

if (placemark.thoroughfare && placemark.subThoroughfare) {
    newPlace = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", placemark.thoroughfare , placemark.subThoroughfare];
}
else {
    if (placemark.thoroughfare) {
        newPlace = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", placemark.thoroughfare];
    }
    else {
        newPlace = @"Unknown Place";
    }
}

item.place = newPlace;    // Either nil of valid string can be assigned to
```

Using release for simply re-initializing pointer is not so recommended by many. You don't have to do this if it was to save some memory.

Your previous logic does releasing **twice**. What release does initially is simply decrementing `retainCount`. If it's 0, then the object is deallocated. Object will not be deallocated until its `retainCount` is 0.

Assuming your **item** has the property **retain** and since `stringWithFormat:` returns `autoreleased` string, so at the 2nd release, you were trying to release what was going to be `autoreleased` anyway.

Best way to clearing an object multiple times is simply assigning `nil` to it.

Comment: I changed it according to your suggestion, but still, instruments shows leaks in strange places. Because the whole project is too big, I have the impression that I have to fix it on my own. Thanks for your help and yes: I went to assigning nil to my retained properties instead of releasing them. Seems much safer and should have the same effect.

Comment: I am glad that my suggestion was helpful. Hope you fix all the leaks!

Answer (score 1):

A starting point would be to re-read about properties because you don't need to do `[item.place release]' anywhere. So you can remove them. The dynamic code created by the runtime to enable that property automatically handles releasing anything previously assigned to it.

Also, the `[NSString stringWithFormat:...` creates an autorelease object (not sure if you knew that :-) which means that if you where manually managing the memory for a variable (not a property) then you would have to retain/release it. But because you are using properties, you don't.

I cannot see why instruments is finding a memory leak. Perhaps some code higher up is to do with it. For example if you went `item.place = [NSString alloc] initWith...];` then I think you would need it.

The crash I would suspect to be because of the releases causing retain counts to be zero and triggering exec bad access errors.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I should have been a bit more verbose in my problem description. Added more information.

Comment: Good. But I think my comments still apply. It would appear that you are "over managing". Start by removing all the releases. The managed object context handles the code for the properties and will manage it correctly.

Comment: ‘But because you are using properties, you don't.’ → well, not always. If it’s an assign property (and assign is a default property attribute), then he’d still need to manage memory, even though it’s not a good idea. Also, it could be the case that he has a custom setter.

Comment: @Bavarious - true. I forgot to mention I was assuming that the properties are set with the retain attribute. Just checked one of my projects and the classes as generated by core data are set with retain on the properties. So hopefully my comments are correct. :-)

Comment: I don't have custom setters. I use @dynamic to generate. But if all the comments are correct, where is the leak? Instruments points me at the place above.

Comment: Ahhh... Ok.  Core data.  A useful clue.

Comment: So - I removed that release-stuff and fixed various other potential problems in other classes, but still, I have that memory leak. Is it possible that instruments assigns leaks to incorrect places?